# Sort Smartgwt menu by menu item title

Tags: java, contextmenu, smartgwt

I have a Context Menu of a grid and it contains menu items. A menu item contains a click handler and a title.

I want to sort the menu items alphabetically by its title. How can I do this ?

Example :

```
Menu contextMenu = new Menu();
MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("title");
menuItem1.addClickHandler(getSomeItemClickHandler);
contextMenu.addItem(menuItem1);
*
*
*
contextMenu.addItem(menuItem10);
```

now I want to sort the complete contextMenu by menuItem title alphabetically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List and other basic java structures should work fine in GWT client side, so if you store them in a List, you sort the List items by your criteria, and use a loop to add them to contextMenu, it will do the job.